# How to delay Ajax and show progress bar while loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have checkbox's in sidebar, When the user selects a checkbox from the sidebar, it show post normally.

**Before showing Ajax result, need to delay it with progress bar??**

**My ajax code:**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('#test .br').click(function(){

    // declaring an array
    var choices = {};

    $('.contents').remove();
    $('.filter-output').empty()

    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        if (!choices.hasOwnProperty(this.name))
            choices[this.name] = [this.value];
        else
            choices[this.name].push(this.value);
    });


    console.log(choices);
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
        type :'POST',
        data : {
            'action' : 'call_post',
            'choices' : choices,
        },

        success: function (result) {
            $('.filter-output').append(result);

        }     
    });
  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Question is far too vague. Take some time to read through [ask] and [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) then update with proper problem statement and details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ajax start/stop handlers:

```
var loading = $('.loader').hide();
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function() {
    loading.show();
  })
  .ajaxStop(function() {
    loading.hide();
  });
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="loader" style="display:none;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Comment: How set delay time??

Comment: @Farooq: could you please explain why you need a delay? Because maybe we could serialize the actions you may need before sending the ajax post...

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.setTimeout()` to execute the ajax on delay.

Edit: If you don't want to delay the ajax call and just delay the response, then you put the timeout inside the success handler:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('#test .br').click(function(){

    // declaring an array
    var choices = {};

    $('.contents').remove();
    $('.filter-output').empty()

    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        if (!choices.hasOwnProperty(this.name))
            choices[this.name] = [this.value];
        else
            choices[this.name].push(this.value);
    });

    // show the progress bar
    $('.progress-bar').show();    

    console.log(choices);

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
        type :'POST',
        data : {
            'action' : 'call_post',
            'choices' : choices,
        },
        success: function (result) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                // hide the progress bar
                $('.progress-bar').hide();

                $('.filter-output').append(result);
            }, 2000);   // Delay displaying the result by 2 seconds
        }
    });

  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Its delay result well,,, That's code display progress-bar??

Comment: @Farooq Updated. You should have a `<div class='progress-bar'>` with whatever progress bar you want to display while you are doing the ajax request

Answer (score 1):

Call your function inside timeout function put your desirable delay time.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   call your function here.
 }, 10);
```